# Azure Service Bus Sender scheduledEnqueueTimeUtc not being respected

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues

We are currently sending batches of messages into a Azure Service Bus queue and setting scheduledEnqueueTimeUtc to schedule them in chunks of 100, one minute apart.   I can see this is set in the Message properties on the Service Bus Explorer on the portal.   However my Azure Functions are still processing these messages on the queue on arrival, not respecting the scheduled enqueue time.  There isn't a lot of examples of folk doing this in javascript and node, I assume I'm setting something wrong?  Relevant sending of message code

```
const { app, output } = require('@azure/functions');
const { ServiceBusClient  } = require('@azure/service-bus');
const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require("@azure/identity");
const moment = require('moment');
const { getAllEmployeeXRefs }  = require('../util/GetAllEmployeeXRefs.js');

const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
const serviceBus = new ServiceBusClient(process.env["ServiceBusConnection__fullyQualifiedNamespace"],credential);
const serviceBusSender = serviceBus.createSender("cacheemployeequeue");


function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
    var myArray = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += size) {
      myArray.push(arr.slice(i, i+size));
    }
    return myArray;
 }


app.http('CacheAllEmployees', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: async (request, context) => {
      

        employeeXrefsToCache = await getAllEmployeeXRefs(filter);
        
        const groupsOfMessages = chunkArrayInGroups(employeeXrefsToCache.Data, 100);
        
        for (let i=0;i<groupsOfMessages.length;i++) {
            
            const batchOfMessages = groupsOfMessages[i];
            const messagesToPush = [];
            for (chunk in batchOfMessages) {
                const message = {
                    body: batchOfMessages[chunk],
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    scheduledEnqueueTimeUtc: moment().add(1*i, 'minutes').format('M/D/YYYY H:mm:ss A')
        
                };
                messagesToPush.push(message);
            }
            await serviceBusSender.sendMessages(messagesToPush);
        }
    
        return  { body: `added ${employeeXrefsToCache.Data.length} to queue` }
    }
});
```

in the Explorer messages look like this (which is correct):

[image]

But the consumption function get them before the scheduled time, as fast as we load them in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scheduledEnqueueTimeUtc: moment().add(1*i, 'minutes').format('M/D/YYYY H:mm:ss A')
```

You're not setting the date and time for the message to be enqueued in UTC format, but rather local time. Therefore, something in the near future not expressed in a correct UTC format would be interpreted as a date/time in the past and will be enqueued immediately. [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/?/displaying/format/#/use-it/node-js/) documentation should help to find the right formatting.

Comment: doh!  thank you.  for those wondering moment.utc(moment().add(1*i, 'minutes')).toDate() does the trick

Comment: You're welcome.